# How to take a jest snapshot after axios fetched data in componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios, jestjs

Component to test

```
class Carousel extends React.Component {
  state = {
    slides: null
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios.get("https://s3.amazonaws.com/rainfo/slider/data.json").then(res => {
      this.setState({ slides: res.data })
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (!slides) {
      return null
    }

    return (
      <div className="slick-carousel">
        ... markup trancated for bravity
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Carousel
```

Test

```
import React from "react"
import renderer from "react-test-renderer"
import axios from "axios"
import Carousel from "./Carousel"

const slides = [
  {
    ID: "114",
    REFERENCE_DATE: "2018-07-02",
    ...
  },
  {
    ID: "112",
    REFERENCE_DATE: "2018-07-06",
    ...
  },
  ...
]

jest.mock("axios")

it("", () => {
  axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ data: slides }))

  const tree = renderer.create(<Carousel />).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

snapshot only records `null`, since at the moment of execution I suppose `state.slides = null`.

Can't put my finger on how to run expectations after axios done fetching the data.

Most of the samples online either use enzyme, or show tests with async functions that return promises. I couldn't find one that would show example only using jest and rendered component.

I tried making test function `async`, also using `done` callback, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in short:

```
it("", async () => {
  axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ data: slides }))

  const tree = renderer.create(<Carousel />);
  await Promise.resolve();
  expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

should do the job

in details: besides you have mocked call to API data is still coming in async way. So we need `toMatchSnapshot` call goes to end of microtasks' queue. `setTimeout(..., 0)` or `setImmediate` will work too but I've found `await Promise.resolve()` being better recognizable as "everything below is coming to end of queue"

[UPD] fixed snippet: `.toJSON` must be after awaiting, object it returns will never be updated

Comment: thanks for the help and good explanation. I was able to come up with `  Promise.resolve(renderer.create(<Carousel />)).then(tree => {
    expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()
  })`, that while I don't get what is doing seemed to be working. Your code, which I ended up using, is much clearer and nicer. Thank you.

Comment: Does this work too if you use `shallow` instead of renderer?

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai if it's shallow rendering and XHR call should happen in some nested child... that will not be rendered because it's shallow rendering - than no, it will not work. But otherwise it should work

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer started to fail the next day. After some tweaking, this seems to be working:

```
import React from "react"
import renderer from "react-test-renderer"
import axios from "axios"
import Carousel from "./Carousel"

jest.mock("axios")
const slides = sampleApiResponse()
const mockedAxiosGet = new Promise(() => ({ data: slides }))
axios.get.mockImplementation(() => mockedAxiosGet)

// eventhough axios.get was mocked, data still comes anychrnonously,
// so during first pass state.slides will remain null
it("returns null initally", () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Carousel />).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})

it("uses fetched data to render carousel", () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Carousel />)
  mockedAxiosGet.then(() => {
    expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})

function sampleApiResponse() {
  return [
    {
      ID: "114",
      REFERENCE_DATE: "2018-07-02",
      ...
    },
    {
      ID: "114",
      REFERENCE_DATE: "2018-07-02",
      ...
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: promise `new Promise(() => ({ data: slides }))` will never be resolved. you need `Promise.resolve()` factory method. using constructor `new Promise()` you need to get resolver as an argument and call it like `new Promise(resolver => resolver({ data: slides }))` but `Promise.resolve()` does exactly the same while having better readability